# Origin of the concepts of chatur-yugas and pralaya?

Tags: yuga, pralaya

It was suggested during a discussion in facebook that the apocalyptic prophecies in Bhagavata Purana and Bhavishya Purana was a result of Christian influence brought into India during the time of apostle St.Thomas(quite possibly a myth) or by early Christians like the Syrian Christians. What is the earliest known source among Hindu texts which talks about the concept of Pralaya and Chaturyuga?

Comment: St. Thomas in India is a myth propagated by early Christian missionaries. There is a good book on this that goes into details. "Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and Dalit Faultlines" by Rajiv Malhotra and Aravindan Neelakandan

Comment: Yes, historians seem to agree that 'St. Thomas in India' is a myth. I'm editing my question to include 'early Christian' as in Syrian Christian who were the first known Christian sect to land in India. Is there any possibility to Syrian Christians influenced the high suspicious prophecies in Bhagawatam and Bhavishya Purana?